# Python Relative Imports but I copied the documentation

Tags: python-3.x, relative-import

I read all the other SO posts about this and it either doesn't work or uses sys.path.append.

**Below is a replica of the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports):**

> All other files not shown are empty

**moduleA.py**

```py
from ..subB.moduleB import MyClass
```

**moduleB.py**

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

**package/subB/__init__.py**

```py
from .moduleB import MyClass
```

#### Traceback from running `moduleA.py`

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\my\projects\folder\package\subA\moduleA.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..subB.moduleB import MyClass
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

#### File Structure

[image: File Structure]

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: As mentioned, I'm running moduleA.py directly with `> py moduleA.py`